# AppCode for reordering code?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, code-formatting, appcode

Is it possible to use AppCode like the ReSharper in a sense that it allows us to reorder code?

In particular I'm looking for a way to reorder methods and properties alphabetically in my Objective-C* files whilst keeping the comments intact.

A plus would be something more sophisticated like Reshaper allows to use a custom scheme that would e.g. first put the initializers, then the protocol implementation, then public and finally private methods.

Up to now I've failed to locate any such feature in the current AppCode 3 demo..

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: Wow, what a horrible idea! Best to order logically top-down. A method followed by any methods it calls, etc.

Comment: Depends on how much you cram into a singe class ;-)  Now think about notifications - I've got a header and implementation file for them (and other string constants). Do I really want to sort them manually?

Comment: "Do I really want to sort them manually?" No, I order them logically. "how much you cram into a singe class" I don't do that either, classes should abide by the Single Responsibility Principle.